# Bein Hashmashot between Yom Tov rishon and Yom tov sheni

Tags: halacha, passover, yom-tov, zemanim, shalosh-regalim

What are the three things forbidden during bein hashmashot between Yom Tov rishon and Yom tov sheni? Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you think there are three things?

Comment: Motion to close as a riddle

Comment: @JoelK yes, because someone asked me

Answer (score 1):

R’ Akiva Eiger in Nedarim 69B and [OC 495:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Rabbi_Akiva_Eiger_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.495.1?lang=bi) famously wonders if it is permitted to cook during bein hashmashos even to eat immediately since the cooking could be on one day and the eating on the next.

In the Haggadah Bais Halevi (1:p275) it says that R’ Chaim Brisker didn’t allow smoking during bein hashmashos for the same reason. The inhale might be on one day and the exhale (enjoyment) is the next day.

In the sefer Yom Tov Sheni Khilchoso (1:21) he brings from R Shlomo Zalman and R Elyashiv that doraisas shouldn’t be done, but drabbanan are ok.

Comment: This applies also to bein hashemashot after the second day into weekday (or first day into weekday in Israel) or into chol hamoed. Hence I thought he wasn't looking for this

Comment: @DoubleAA on the same token it could apply to bein hashmashos of shabbosim as well. Is bringing water to the table during Shalosh seudas s problem of hachana? You might be drinking it after shabbos? I thought that since you need havdala is still shabbos or YT. But YT Sheni is automatic. It’s just what I understood, No source

Comment: No, the issue here is not hachana but a lack of the heter of ochel nefesh. It's a potential deorayta problem. Cooking on Yom tov for chol is like cooking for dogs. Melakha with no heter.

Comment: I know that. So your saying that since hachana is drabbanan we’re not worried about these things?

Comment: More like chazal were never gozer that. It's different from the position here of RSZA not to worry about ochel nefesh derbanan; that's just because he's mesupak about the din and is being lenient.